# What will happen in a twin paradox like situation if acceleration is not involved?

Tags: special-relativity

I have known about the twin paradox for some time and as far as I know that it's not a paradox because one of the twins accelerate in his return journey.

But if this is not the case, then what will they see when they meet each other? If by some means the twins synchronize their clocks when the space twin reaches his ending point and then on his return journey both of the twins' clocks start at $0$ from the beginning of the return journey, then the effect of acceleration will be removed from the time taken for the return journey.

So they when they meet each other and can compare each others' clocks. What will they see then? A will see B's clock to run slow and B will see A's clock to run slow. Will they see that both their clocks has measured the same time for the return journey?

Here A is the twin who goes from point X to point Y at uniform velocity and B is the twin who stays at point X.

**Edit:** Suppose A sends light signal from Y to X and the light signal reaches X and is immediately reflected by a mirror. The it will go back to Y where it will once again be reflected back to X. In the above case, the light will take 2 years to go from X to Y and back to X. So A will figure out that light takes 1 year to cover the distance XY. When light reaches B for the second time (3 years after the first signal), he will start his clock from $0$.

And also after 3 years A will start his return journey with starting his clock from $0$. So both of the clocks will start from $0$ exactly 3 years after the first signal was sent.

Comment: What does "synchronize their clocks" mean?  It turns out that the answer to your question depends entirely on the implementation of this process, as it means sending a signal (typically via light) from one to the other at a long distance.  The nature of that signalling will affect how they set their clocks, and thus the numbers they read back home.

Comment: @CortAmmon I have edited the answer to include the process.

Comment: The usual way to synchronize seoarated clocks that are at rest relative to each other is [Einstein synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation), but there are [other options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light#Generalizations_of_Lorentz_transformations_with_anisotropic_one-way_speeds).

Comment: You haven't defined properly who is A and who is B. Also you haven't properly defined the points X and Y. No answer can be given unless you are precise on the definitions. I suspect that once you try to be precise you will indeed discover your mistake.

Comment: If you want to take out acceleration, just bring in a clone of the traveling twin that is on another rocket coming towards the Earth, and represent the turn around as the clone passing the traveling twin where they synchronize watches. Would this be better for what you are trying to ask?

Comment: @Noumeno I seem to have deleted it in the process of editing. I will clearify it.

Comment: @Biophysicist:  What turnaround?   Were you intending to comment on some other question?

Comment: @WillO Usually in the twin paradox the twin on the rocket turns around and comes back to Earth. Why not just ask me what I meant instead of implying that I'm unaware of what I'm reading?

Answer (score 3):

$B$ is the twin who remains on earth.  $A$ is the twin who  starts at $Y$ and travels to earth.

There are two frames here:  The $B$-frame (which is $B$'s frame throughout and also $A$'s frame before he starts his journey) and the $A$-frame (which is $A$'s frame once the journey starts).

Your procedure synchronizes the clocks in the $B$ frame.  They are not synchronized in the $A$ frame.

Here is the story in the $B$-frame:

1. When both clocks read $0$, $A$ starts his journey.
2. The journey takes $1$ year.  During that year, $A$'s clock runs at 1/2 speed, but $B$'s runs normally.
3. Therefore when $A$ arrives, $A$'s clock says $1/2$, and $B$'s clock says $1$.

Here is the story in the $A$ frame (where it's $B$ who does all the traveling):

1. When $A$'s clock says $0$, $B$'s clock says $3/4$, and he's already partway along his journey.
2. The remainder of the journey takes half a year.  During that time, $B$'s clock runs at half speed (so that it advances by 1/4 of a year) while $A$'s run normally.
3. Therefore when $B$ arrives, $A$'s clock says $1/2$ and $B$'s clock says $1$.

I arrived at all this not by thinking about time dilation or clocks running slow, but by meditating on the geometry of the spacetime diagram.  Only after I understood it did I translate it into the language of "clocks running slow".  In other words, m4r35n357 basically gave you good advice.

Comment: I couldn't agree with your penultimate sentence more!  Folks:  the spacetime diagram (and spacetime interval, effectively the same thing) are the ultimate truth, they should be your _first_ port of call for _all_ SR problems.  Worry about the buzzwords _after_ you have calculated the answer ;)

Comment: Since your spacetime diagram was useful in resolving the issue, can you update your answer with it? It could help others.

Comment: @robphy :  If I find time, I will.  Meanwhile, I've included diagrams in my answers to dozens of similar questions, all of which are easy to find by clicking on my username (and I know you've done the same, so your username works too).

Comment: @WillO I can't understand how A's clock will say 0 when B's clock say 3/4.

Comment: @Theoretical:  Draw the picture.

Comment: @WillO I can't properly draw the diagrams and I have looked for the diagrams in your answer but the app is showing no answers of yours in special relativity when I searched using this tag. Just explain clearly why the clocks will not be synchronized in the A frame.

Comment: Perhaps @robphy could post an answer that uses some of his nice spacetime diagrams on rotated graph paper... ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring : I think the OP would be much better served by doing this on his/her own.

Comment: @Theoretical:  here's the algebra your picture should reflect:  1)  By calculating in the B frame, we know that when the two come together, A's clock must say 1/2 and B's must say 1.  2)  By calculating in the A frame, we know that between time 0 and time 1/2, the time elapsed on B's clock must be 1/4.  3)  From 1) and 2) we know that in the A frame, when A's clock reads 0, B's must read 3/4.

Comment: I'm was trying to encourage the inclusion of the reasoning (the process) that leads to the construction of the spacetime diagram... since it is claimed that this is what led to the answer (here, only given in translated form in "the language of 'clocks running slow' ").

Answer (score 0):

The problem is they can't synchronize their clocks unless they are in the same place. In relativity, you need to keep in mind that there is no "universal now".

Comment: A long process had come up in my mind. So I did not want to include it in my question. I think I have to put it now.

Comment: @Ken Absolutely true of course, but hardly an answer!

Comment: @Ken Why can't they snchronize their clocks? I would be great if you would elaborare your answer.

Comment: @Theoretical hope you didn't find my answer too patronizing, but if you look at my comment below it I address the reading of a remote clock ;)

Answer (score -1):

Acceleration is **absolutely not necessary** to understand the "Twin Paradox".  Furthermore, it is a significant *impediment* to understanding the "Twin Paradox".  The "Twin Paradox" is a great example of a really basic concept badly taught over many decades.

If you learn about the [spacetime interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval), $\delta \tau^2 = \delta t^2 - \delta x^2$, you will know what *all* the participants' clocks say, at *every* stage of the process.  Specifically, here is the time shown on the traveler's clock:

$$\delta \tau^2 = (1 / v^2 - 1) \delta x^2$$

Anyone with basic algebra skills will be able to derive this in *two lines* starting from the Spacetime Interval together with $v = \delta x / \delta t$ (taking $c = 1$).  So why make them worry about acceleration on top of that?

If you get hung up on distractions like "acceleration", "clocks running slow", "time dilation" and puzzle over things happening "at the same time" you will *never* gain an understanding.

[EDIT] following @Not_Einstein's comment, perhaps I should add that for the non-traveler, the time elapsed is simply $\delta \tau = \delta t$, the coordinate time, since $\delta x = 0$.  I had not considered this useful (visual clutter), but I am adding it now anyway.

Comment: The tone of this post is patronizing, and it is not an answer.  It is only a hint that *you* know the answer.   Someone with the apparent background of the OP will not be able derive the solution in two lines.  Please provide a complete answer.  I'll also note that the usual statement of the twin paradox has the twins meeting at some future time after they leave each other so that they can compare their clocks.  To explain your version of the twin paradox you will have to explain how the twins compare their clocks. (downvoted)

Comment: While acceleration may not be necessary to explain the twin paradox to someone versed in the mathematics of special relativity, it is useful to differentiate the traveling twin from the earthbound one to someone not so versed.

Comment: @garyp I know you understand this, but for others my point is that acceleration is an unnecessary distraction, since if the traveler never turned around and just went twice as far, his age would be the same as if he _had_ turned round.  The non-traveler would of course need to read the traveler's clock remotely (or the traveler could transmit it), but this can be done in principle.  Thus the turn-around (and therefore the "acceleration" phase) is ripe for Occam's Razor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: Please re-read the first sentence of the OP before agreeing that this is _not_ an answer.

Comment: @m4r35n357 How can this happen then? Doesn't Lorentz Tranformation imply that both of them will experience time dilation?

Comment: Yes, because that is a device that I came up with for this question, that _is_ symmetrical and has no acceleration element.  However, the aging calculation is the same.  So, the situation I described has exactly the same aging calculation as the "Twin Paradox", but without acceleration.  Therefore, as you asked in the OP, acceleration is _not_ the root cause of the "paradox"; the spacetime interval (metric) is.  Hope you have had the chance to look at the Wikipedia link ;)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but you are answering a question not asked.  The twin paradox asks:  Why did one twin age while the other didn't?  Isn't relativity symmetrical?  The reason is that one twin accelerated while the other did not.  You are making a correct (but completely void of detail) statement about time dilation for two observers in uniform relative motion.

Comment: Please refer again to the OP title and first sentence.  It is _your_ question that has not been asked.  The OP is asking specifically and explicitly about the role of acceleration in the TP, and  that is precisely the aspect I have focused on.  If I thought the poster was merely asking for yet another description of the TP I would not have bothered answering at all.

Comment: It may come down to this:  I think that all three of us agree that the travelling twin changes frame.  My point of view is that the change of frame *is* an acceleration.   The OP tries to eliminate it by breaking it up into two parts with a synchronization between them.  That can't happen without an acceleration (two, in the OP's scheme). There's a classic space-time diagram taken from the "stationary" twin's frame showing two world lines for the traveler, with the two lines meeting at a sharp corner.  The analysis is completely geometrical, but still an acceleration happens.

Comment: And my point is that the traveler is the same age when he has gone the given distance whether or not he accelerates half way along.  Acceleration has no effect on the ages of the traveler or the non traveler.  To get me to agree with you, show me a mathematical expression (relevant to the TP) containing the acceleration, $a$.

Comment: Yes," the same age...whether or not he accelerates half way along." But the paradox as usually stated is that he returns to the earth and is younger than his twin. So we need a way for him to return to the earth.

Comment: @garyp For all inertial observers, B has a straight worldline, and A has a bend in his worldline. Yes, that bend happens because of acceleration, but it's the change of frame that is the ultimate cause of the difference in proper times of A & B, *not* the acceleration, per se, since we can eliminate the acceleration by introducing a traveling clone, [as mentioned above by BioPhysicist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564188/what-will-happen-in-a-twin-paradox-like-situation-if-acceleration-is-not-involve#comment1273918_564188).

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, that's not the twin paradox.  We shouldn't be discussing thin in comments.  I'm happy to leave things as they are because I think we understand each other except for the philosophical or semantic question of whether an acceleration is distinct from a change of frame.

Comment: @garyp Yes. You have clearly stated what I have wanted to express in my question. But now it seems that even without acceleration the result will not be symmetrical. Then what are examples where we can experience the symmetry of lorentz transformation?